# Do maximal compact logics exist?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

By "logic" I mean regular logic in the sense of abstract model theory (see e.g. the last section of [Ebbinghaus/Flum/Thomas' book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2355-7)). My question is simple:

> Is there a logic $\mathcal{L}$ which is fully compact and such that no properly-stronger logic is fully compact?

It seems like there should be an easy negative answer as long as the logics are required to be set-sized, but I can't quite get the details to work; the *relativizability* property of regular logics makes everything rather tedious. And if we allow class-sized logics (e.g. $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$, although of course that's not fully compact) then this idea goes out the window and I have no intuition.

I'm happy to add any definability criteria which would help, but I do *not* want to add Lowenheim-Skolem-type conditions. In particular, the results of [Shelah/Vaananen (*A note on extensions of infinitary logic*)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00153-004-0212-8) don't seem to apply here.